# How do I allow user to edit title of Folder in Document Library?

Tags: wss-3.0

How can I allow a user to edit the Title of folder separately from the folder's name?  I've done it by accident, messing with the content types.

I found that I could add a custom content type that inherits from folder, but then there is the drop-down that lets you pick which type of folder. I'd like to keep it simple.  Also, I need to programmatically deploy such a change.

Comment: Have you checked the Permission on the folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable management of content types on your list folder should show up as an option (Assuming WSS3 like in your tag - this no longer works in 2010) From there you can add fields to your folder or in the case of title, make it required or optional instead of hidden.

All of these settings should be accessible through the API as well.

- SPList.ContentTypesEnabled should allow you to enable management of content types.
- SPList.ContentTypes["Folder"].FieldLinks["Title"].Hidden should allow you to flip hidden to false

I have not tested this but theoretically it should work. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: To finish the code::> 
`lib = GetLib(web, libname);
lib.ContentTypes["Folder"].FieldLinks["Title"].Hidden=false;
lib.ContentTypes["Folder"].Update();`

Comment: Yeah that update call would be important. Good catch there. Glad I could help.